# Multiple Definition of __stderr , __stdin , __stdout Linker error

Tags: c++, c, linker, linker-errors

In my project there's a mix of c and cpp files , when I try to build the project using arm cc , the libraries of individual modules are successfully created but during linking I am getting errors like,

21:07:22,285 INFO  - Error: L6200E: Symbol __stderr multiply defined (by stdio_streams.o and console.o).

21:07:22,302 INFO  - Error: L6200E: Symbol __stdout multiply defined (by stdio_streams.o and console.o).

21:07:22,311 INFO  - Error: L6200E: Symbol __stdin multiply defined (by stdio_streams.o and console.o).

Can anyone here help me to overcome this issue.
I have commented out all the "iostream.h" in cpp files, but still facing the same issue.

Comment: `iostream.h` is not a standard header. cook up a small but complete example please

Comment: My project is entirely of c files till now. I now have written a module in c++ and I am trying to integrate it to the project. The building of my module is fine with library generated , but during linking I am seeing the above errors. I am not using any "iostream" headers in cpp files.

Comment: Are `stdio_streams.o` and/or `console.o` files you wrote? If at least one is, the problem is that you're using an illegal name. If both are, then on top of that you also have a problem that you're defining the same symbol in multiple translation units.

Comment: No I not writing any such files @R..